# TypeError: Cannot find function find in object

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

This is frustrating. I thought the problem was the object being returned by the api response. Maybe it's in string so what I did was I copied the response from "postman" and paste it directly on the js. This way im sure that it's in object/array. But the result was the same error.

Why is my code not working on netsuite. The code below is very simple. Tried running it on my local machine and it worked. Does .find not supported in netsuite?

```js
var tasks_data = new Array();
  var tasks_data = [
    {
      'id': 10376401,
      'name': 'closed',
      'notes': null,
      'start_date': '2017-12-23',
      'end_date': '2018-01-07',
      'start_time': null,
      'end_time': null,
      'color': '#f99bd0',
      'color_id': 5,
      'estimated_hours': 0,
      'done': false,
      'user_id': 961775,
      'project_id': null,
      'project': null,
      'folder_id': null,
      'weight': 0,
      'created_at': '2017-11-13T00:58:16.577+00:00',
      'updated_at': '2017-11-13T00:58:16.577+00:00',
      'deleted_at': null
    },
    {
      'id': 10438883,
      'name': '',
      'notes': null,
      'start_date': '2018-02-17',
      'end_date': '2018-02-17',
      'start_time': null,
      'end_time': null,
      'color': '#ccaf53',
      'color_id': 36,
      'estimated_hours': 0,
      'done': false,
      'user_id': 961775,
      'project_id': 1501267,
      'project': {
        'id': 1501267,
        'name': 'sue',
        'color': '#ccaf53',
        'color_id': 36,
        'client': null,
        'created_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:11.459+00:00',
        'updated_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:11.459+00:00'
      },
      'folder_id': null,
      'weight': 0,
      'created_at': '2017-11-17T03:15:48.055+00:00',
      'updated_at': '2017-11-17T03:15:48.055+00:00',
      'deleted_at': null
    },
    {
      'id': 10438875,
      'name': 'Sue',
      'notes': null,
      'start_date': '2018-01-27',
      'end_date': '2018-01-27',
      'start_time': null,
      'end_time': null,
      'color': '#ccaf53',
      'color_id': 36,
      'estimated_hours': 0,
      'done': false,
      'user_id': 961775,
      'project_id': 1501267,
      'project': {
        'id': 1501267,
        'name': 'sue',
        'color': '#ccaf53',
        'color_id': 36,
        'client': null,
        'created_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:11.459+00:00',
        'updated_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:11.459+00:00'
      },
      'folder_id': null,
      'weight': 0,
      'created_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:11.903+00:00',
      'updated_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:50.363+00:00',
      'deleted_at': null
    }
  ];

  // var result = output_result(tasks_data)
  var result = tasks_data.reduce(function (acc, item) {
    var task = acc.find(function (accItem) {
      return accItem.project_id === item.project_id
    })
    if (task && !Array.isArray(task.schedule)) {
      task.schedule = [task.schedule].concat({
        project_id: item.project_id,
        start_date: item.start_date,
        end_date: item.end_date,
        daily_estimate: item.estimated_hours,
      })
      task.start_dates.push(item.start_date)
      task.end_dates.push(item.end_date)
      task.next_start_dates.push(item.start_date)
    } else if (task && Array.isArray(task.schedule)) {
      task.schedule.push({
        project_id: item.project_id,
        start_date: item.start_date,
        end_date: item.end_date,
        daily_estimate: item.estimated_hours,
      })
      task.start_dates.push(item.start_date)
      task.end_dates.push(item.end_date)
      task.next_start_dates.push(item.start_date)
    } else {
      acc.push({
        project_id: item.project_id, //(item.project_id === null) ? 'Missing_project_id' : item.project_id,
        schedule: [{
          project_id: item.project_id, //(item.project_id === null) ? 'Missing_project_id' : item.project_id,
          start_date: item.start_date,
          end_date: item.end_date,
          daily_estimate: item.estimated_hours,
        }],
        start_dates: [item.start_date],
        end_dates: [item.end_date],
        next_start_dates: [item.start_date],
      })
    }

    return acc
  }, [])
  
  console.log(result)
```

```html
<body>
Hello
</body>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should work. If `find` wasn’t supported, `reduce` should’ve caused an error before `find`. And `find` is always used on an array, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Not sure what netsuite runs, but maybe the engine it uses does not support it. Maybe add the polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: I haven't done any polyfill before.

Comment: @epascarello, it worked. I added a polyfill for find. thanks mate

Answer (score 5):

I see you added a polyfill to solve the problem, but the answer to your question is that NetSuite/SuiteScript uses **ECMAScript 5.1**; its engine is Java Rhino (unsure which version).

`find` was added in ES6, while `reduce` was added in ES5.1, so SuiteScript does not support `find` while it does support `reduce`.

Sources:

- Reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Specifications
- Find: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Find#Specifications